# FullCalendar failed to display events in calendar

Tags: laravel

I am using FullCalendar in laravel 8 project and I use it to display all the events from the database.

This is the code:

**My controller**

```
public function index(Request $request, $id) {
    $patient = [];
    $listOfPatients = [];
    $appointments = [];

    //apply permission constraits
    $patient = Patient::find($id);
    $listOfPatients = Patient::all();
    $appointments = appointments::all();


    $this->authorize('view', $patient);

    // $appointments = $patient->remarks()->get()->sortBy([['id', 'desc']]);

    if($request->ajax()) {  
        $data = appointments::whereDate('start', '>=', $request->start)
            ->whereDate('end',   '<=', $request->end)
            ->get(['id', 'title', 'description', 'start', 'end']);
        return response()->json($data);
    }

    return view('patient.appointments', [ "appointments" => $appointments, "patient" => $patient, "listOfPatients" => $listOfPatients]);

}
```

**My js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var SITEURL = "{{ url('/') }}";
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var calendar = $('#full_calendar_events').fullCalendar({
            editable: false,
            editable: false,


            eventSources: [
                {
                    url: '/{id}/appointments',
                    color: '#65a9d7',    // an option!
                    textColor: '#3c3d3d'  // an option!

                }                    
            ],
            

            
        });
    });
```

I also got this error:

jquery.min.js:4          GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/%7Bid%7D/appointments?start=2022-02-27&end=2022-04-10&_=1648373948124 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Does `url: '/{id}/appointments',` missing the double accolades? `{{id}}`? Because it is parsed as `%7Bid%7D` in your link, and I think this should be the ID value?

Comment: tried doing that but still not working